# A software that treat an LiveCD or LiveDVD like an exe file and run it

Tags: iso, live-preview

There are many LiveCD and/or LiveDVD (in ISO file format) showcase many variants of Linux operating system. Currently, user use VirtualBox or any similar virtualization software to run it.

[image]

Is there a software that allow you to drop the ISO file into it and it will run the LiveCD or LiveDVD using the least possible resource (such as CPU and memory) to run it smoothly and self-adjust when more resource or less resource are needed.

This is because one need to set all those settings in the virtualization software before they can run the ISO file.

This question only apply to LiveCD and/or LiveDVD ISO file.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

"run it smoothly", as you call it, is a highly subjective human concept, that doesn't mean much to a machine.

How would a piece of software, like VirtualBox (or similar), know what you mean by "smooth" and what characteristics are required to run an OS "smoothly"? The parameters are so many and so varied that I doubt a software could figure it out by itself.

The best you can do, in my opinion, is use the [VirtualBox command line](http://www.howopensource.com/2011/06/how-to-use-virtualbox-in-terminal-commandline/) to write a script/app that automatically configures the Virtual Machines with a set of parameters that you think are fit to make the OS run "smoothly". As for what those parameters are, I'm afraid you'll need to test for yourself.